# how to take a JPEG out of IplImage* and not saving it to hard drive put saved dat into char*?

Tags: c, opencv, cross-platform, char, jpeg

So what I need is simple: I have `IplImage*` I want to encode it into JPEG and wrap it with some additional JPEG data if needed (JPEG files contain noty only encoded pixels) and put tha file (not saved onto hard drive) into char* buffer. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

JPEG is a complex format. You can use the IJG jpeg library as a base to work with. However, be warned, it is a mess in itself and has a slight learning curve. It is open source, and you'll typically need to configure its build according to your compiler using a provided makefile (which may not be found with the library code itself)

Comment: could you provide any code sample showing if and how it is possible?

Comment: I think it would lend more to confusing you. I have some code that I wrote long ago. It is very hard to follow due to the nature of IJG. The best way to learn is with the documentation provided with IJG. However, IJG is set up to work with file streams, and special measures are needed to set the library up to work in memory rather than a file. If you email me tomorrow I will send you my source code. It's not for the faint of heart and probably won't learn you anything. My email is listed in my profile.